# Send unsolicited application for a different location

Tags: job-search, applications, location

I am currently on a job hunt and found a company that I would really like to work for. They have offices in three cities A,B,C (in europe, about 600km apart) with the main office in city A. On the homepage they advertise positions in city A that really fit my profile and are kind of my dream job. Only problem is I live in city B and I would prefer not to relocate at the moment. I am however up for travelling to city A or C anytime if necessary.

Do you think it’s a good idea to send such an unsolicited application for city B? How would you phrase an opening statement to explain my situation and ask if it’s even possible to work at city B?

I am confident that I can explain why I would be a perfect candidate for the position they offer and that what the company does (at least what they advertise on the homepage) is exactly what I want to do in my career. The worst thing that can happen is they say no. But I am unsure how to phrase my application.

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Did the job description mention anything about (possibly) working in the other offices or remote working? That might help you get an idea of how flexible they might be. No guarantees though.

Comment: It says they offer "flexible hours and workplaces (home office)" and it's a job that could be done from anywhere with a computer except when you have to meet clients. I am under the impression that they are quite flexible.

Answer (score 6):

At least here in Germany "unsolicited" applications are quite normal (Initiativbewerbung). In your case it´s not even that unsolicited at all, because you have the skill-set they are currently looking for.

Go ahead and apply - it can not hurt you (other than the time involved). Companies are always happy to be offered talent, and even *if* they can not offer you a position in your desired location currently, that can change in the future - so it is always good to have a foot in the door already!

Answer (score 0):

I would contact the office in city B (via email or phone) and ask if the desired position is available at their site at all. It's quite common to centralize certain departments like accounting in city A, software development in city B and marketing in city C, so your job might not be available in city B.

If they have jobs in your position or are open to remote work, send your application with a reference to the information you got in that first email / call. State that you are willing to travel, but not to relocate.